# How are edits performed on files in Gitlab UI

Tags: git, gitlab

My application requires to provide a UI where the users make changes to file and the files are version controlled. Question I am scratching my head is, if the user is interacting with git repo through a web application (like editing and committing it ) where would be the file be checked out like the local repo.

Along those lines I have seen Gitlab which provides similar functionality where users can directly go and edit and commit the files. In this case (the functionality I am looking for) what is happening under the hood, is the file being checked out, if so where?

Answer (score 1):

That is what **satellite** repos are for: in the "[Components](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/367dee33e260fec07c6ebaf4e10b76e6dcda816d/doc/development/architecture.md#components)" section of the [GitLab architure](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/367dee33e260fec07c6ebaf4e10b76e6dcda816d/doc/development/architecture.md), you can see them described as:

> GitLab stores the bare git repositories it serves in `/home/git/repositories` by default.
> It also keeps default branch and hook information with the bare repository.
> **`/home/git/gitlab-satellites` keeps checked out repositories when performing actions such as a merge request, editing files in the web interface, etc**.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/367dee33e260fec07c6ebaf4e10b76e6dcda816d/doc/development/gitlab_diagram_overview.png]

The [maintenance document](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/56a456b43dba7d772db45e2b73aa18b5eab53d37/doc/raketasks/maintenance.md#re-create-satellite-repositories) describes how to (re-)create satellite repositories:

> This will create satellite repositories for all your projects.
>
> If necessary, remove the `repo_satellites` directory and rerun the commands below.

```
sudo -u git -H mkdir -p /home/git/gitlab-satellites
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:satellites:create RAILS_ENV=production
sudo chmod u+rwx,g=rx,o-rwx /home/git/gitlab-satellites
```

Comment: VonC, your answer takes me to the next question, Say I am replicating the same workflow for my case, I assume the satellite in my case is a branch from master (Correct me if this assumption is wrong). Then how can I make changes to this branch from a web app. Should I need to make a clone of it locally to make a change to branch(satellite) as it is git controlled. In that case it depletes the purpose of satellite. I know Gitlab does it somehow but I cannot see it by myself.